# How to create a table whose name is taken from a string in PostgreSQL?

Tags: c, postgresql, embedded-database

I'm writing an embedded SQL application in C language.
The application receives a string from a function and I need to create a table whose name is taken from that string. 
I have to create several tables with different names, but I don't know the number and the name of the tables from the start.

This is what i want to do:

```
tablename = function();
...
EXEC SQL CREATE TABLE :tablename ( ... );
```

But I got this error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near ":tablename"
```

Comment: what is exactly `EXEC SQL CREATE TABLE :` in `c`?

Comment: First create a string containing a piece of SQL and then execute this piece of SQL. Beware of SQL injection, you might loose everything.... Check the quote_ident() function in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to create the same data structures but with unique names then create procedure that creates such table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_temp_table(table_name varchar)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' ||  quote_ident(table_name) || ' (id SERIAL, kn VARCHAR, kv VARCHAR)';
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You can call it from SQL via:

```
SELECT create_temp_table('tmp_table_31');
```

(notice use of `quote_ident()` to prevent SQL Injection)